@Valid is automatcally added in my swagger generated dto
I am generating DTO from swagger but it is adding @Valid annotation on its own. Please check if you can help!!
sharing the jsons basically roles and employees two entities having many to many relationship and this roles inside employee is generated with @Valid annotation.
{
  "title": "Role Data Transfer Object",
  "description": "Represents a role in the system.",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "Unique identifier for the role."
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Name of the role."
    }
  }
}

{
  "title": "Employee Data Transfer Object",
  "description": "Represents a employee in the system.",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer",
      "description": "Unique identifier for the role."
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Name of the employee."
    },
    "username": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "UserName of the employee."
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "Password of the employee."
    },
    "roles": {
      "type": "array",
      "description": "Roles assigned to the employee.",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "./role-details-dto.json"
      }
    }
  }
}


//generated dto
package com.byr.leave_managent.model;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Objects;
import com.byr.leave_managent.model.RoleDetailsDto;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.openapitools.jackson.nullable.JsonNullable;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;


import java.util.*;
import javax.annotation.Generated;

/**
 * Represents a employee in the system.
 */

@Schema(name = "employee-details-dto", description = "Represents a employee in the system.")
@JsonTypeName("employee-details-dto")
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2024-12-01T17:52:45.245419200+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]")
public class EmployeeDetailsDto {

  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  private String username;

  private String password;

  @Valid
  private List<@Valid RoleDetailsDto> roles;

  public EmployeeDetailsDto id(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Unique identifier for the role.
   * @return id
  */
  
  @Schema(name = "id", description = "Unique identifier for the role.", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.NOT_REQUIRED)
  @JsonProperty("id")
  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public EmployeeDetailsDto name(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Name of the employee.
   * @return name
  */
  
  @Schema(name = "name", description = "Name of the employee.", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.NOT_REQUIRED)
  @JsonProperty("name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public EmployeeDetailsDto username(String username) {
    this.username = username;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * UserName of the employee.
   * @return username
  */
  
  @Schema(name = "username", description = "UserName of the employee.", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.NOT_REQUIRED)
  @JsonProperty("username")
  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public EmployeeDetailsDto password(String password) {
    this.password = password;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Password of the employee.
   * @return password
  */
  
  @Schema(name = "password", description = "Password of the employee.", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.NOT_REQUIRED)
  @JsonProperty("password")
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public EmployeeDetailsDto roles(List<@Valid RoleDetailsDto> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
    return this;
  }

  public EmployeeDetailsDto addRolesItem(RoleDetailsDto rolesItem) {
    if (this.roles == null) {
      this.roles = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.roles.add(rolesItem);
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Roles assigned to the employee.
   * @return roles
  */
  @Valid 
  @Schema(name = "roles", description = "Roles assigned to the employee.", requiredMode = Schema.RequiredMode.NOT_REQUIRED)
  @JsonProperty("roles")
  public List<@Valid RoleDetailsDto> getRoles() {
    return roles;
  }

  public void setRoles(List<@Valid RoleDetailsDto> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    EmployeeDetailsDto employeeDetailsDto = (EmployeeDetailsDto) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.id, employeeDetailsDto.id) &&
        Objects.equals(this.name, employeeDetailsDto.name) &&
        Objects.equals(this.username, employeeDetailsDto.username) &&
        Objects.equals(this.password, employeeDetailsDto.password) &&
        Objects.equals(this.roles, employeeDetailsDto.roles);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, name, username, password, roles);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class EmployeeDetailsDto {\n");
    sb.append("    id: ").append(toIndentedString(id)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    name: ").append(toIndentedString(name)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    username: ").append(toIndentedString(username)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    password: ").append(toIndentedString(password)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    roles: ").append(toIndentedString(roles)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }
}




sharing my pom

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.byr.employee</groupId>
    <artifactId>leave-managent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>leave-managent</name>
    <description>Employee Leave Management System</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version> <!-- Use a compatible version -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version> <!-- Compatible with Spring Boot 3.x -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version> <!-- Use the latest version -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.36</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.byr.employee.leavemanagent.LeaveManagentApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-api</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                            <apiPackage>com.byr.leave-managent.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.byr.leave-managent.model</modelPackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


How to remove this valid annotation as it will give error
@Valid not applicable to type use
